# How to convert Int8 to Character?

Tags: swift

I need to convert `Int8` to `Character`. How can I do it?

I tried use `UnicodeScalar`

```
var result += Character(UnicodeScalar(data[i]))
```

... but got this error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnicodeScalar' with an argument
>   list of type (Int8)

Comment: Your input is a *signed* integer. What result would you expect for negative values, e.g. for `-50` ?

Comment: @MartinR Fatal error: Negative value is not representable: D But seriously, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Unicode.Scalar` can be initalized just with paramaters of certain types which you can find in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar).

I would suggest you using [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/2904991-init) which takes `UInt8` which tells that given number is positive (this is required for creating `UnicodeScalar`). So, you can try to cast your `Int8` to `UInt8` and then your initializer takes parameter of correct type

```
let int: Int8 = data[i]
if let uint = UInt8(exactly: int) {
    let char = Character(UnicodeScalar(uint))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! It works for me! Is this the only way? Look at my question, I made it a bit shorter

Comment: @SBlintsov what? What will happen if `UnicodeScalar` can't be constructed? It would return `nil`. So, you need to unwrap it. In this case safely using optional binding, so yes, this `if let` is necessary.

Comment: @SBlintsov btw, don't edit your question with my answer and rather accept answer by clicking to mark.

Comment: I did not delete if-let construction. I just deleted the first string in your answer and replaced "if let scalar = UnicodeScalar(Int(int))" with "if let scalar = UnicodeScalar(Int(data[i]))". It is right?

Comment: @SBlintsov yes ofc, this is right. I just created this constant for showing type of given value

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need just convert whole data to a string:

```
var result = String(data: data, encoding: .ascii)
```

Comment: "data" in arguments should have "data" type. I use Int8 type inside data.

Comment: Yes. If you have an array of type [Int8] you could convert it into Data

data.withUnsafeBufferPointer { pointer in
    let _data = Data(buffer: pointer)
    var result = String(data: _data, encoding: .ascii)
}